# Showing algebraic sets are irreducible

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I've come across with examples of decompositions of algebraic sets into irreducible ones, but I'm confused on how they justify the sets are irreducible. They show $V$ is irreducible by showing $K[X,Y,Z]/I(V)$ is an integral domain. So does that show $I(V)$ is prime, hence $V$ irreducible? How do I prove this implication? Also, how to show $V$ is irreducible when it is not prime?

Thanks

Comment: I'm sure that a full proof of $I \subseteq A$ prime $\Leftrightarrow$ $A/I$ a domain is spelled out somewhere, but try to prove it. Regarding the correspondence of "irreducible" and "prime" I again think that this is a good exercise, but if you get stuck see, eg, Prop 2.19 of [Milne's book](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/AG.pdf).

Comment: @Hoot Sorry I didn't mean $K[X,Y,Z]/V$, I meant as in this example http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~tfylam/Math221/3.pdf what theorem is being used there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, in the [link](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~tfylam/Math221/3.pdf) you gave the field is assumed *algebraically closed*.

Moreover, a variety $V$ is irreducible if and only if $I(V)$ is a prime ideal; see e.g. [here](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~r-ash/Algebra/Chapter8.pdf) (page 3), or [here](http://books.google.ro/books?id=yCsDO425PC0C&pg=PA198&lpg=PA198&dq=%22V+is+irreducible+if+and+only+if+I%28V%29+is+a+prime+ideal%22&source=bl&ots=_G35OC3W89&sig=JVWJj5GeByAhDglVVHHumCnuYBs&hl=en&sa=X&ei=tWpsU5rPF-O57AbmiYC4Bg&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22V%20is%20irreducible%20if%20and%20only%20if%20I%28V%29%20is%20a%20prime%20ideal%22&f=false). Or, for an algebraically closed field, $I(V(I))=\sqrt I$. If $I$ is a prime ideal, then $\sqrt I=I$ (hence a prime ideal) and you are done.

In that example $V=V(f_1,f_2)$ with $f_1=y+x^2, f_2=-1+2x+y$. Then the radical of ideal $I=(f_1,f_2)$ equals $(x-1,y+1)$ and this is easily seen a prime ideal.

Comment: in the link I gave he factorises the second generator incorrectly.